# What is the use of name and slot in the styled API?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, emotion

I am using MUI to create my own component library. I was tempted to use the `styled` API to use create all components and their sub-components. But later I found out that in order to override any style of a component or a subcomponent, I would need to pass my own className as noted [here](https://github.com/mui/material-ui/issues/34689#issuecomment-1278570756).
This applies to styling via `sx` prop as well as `styled` API.

Another place where I thought the name and slot would help is in theming using createTheme, but it [seems](https://github.com/mui/material-ui/issues/34689#issuecomment-1278570756) that it actually relies on the overridesResolver to do that.

The only place where the name and slot was useful was in creating the `className` for the component (that too hash prefixed, so useless for CSS targeting) and the displayName in the React devtools.

Am I missing anything?

Answer (score 1):

For reference it is explained with examples on the **[styled MUI docs page](https://mui.com/system/styled/#api)**.

The **name** property chooses the overrides and variants in your theme based on the key used under *theme.components*. For overrides, these are the css rules passed to the second argument of the styled `overridesResolver` function. You can use this function to conditionally choose (based on props) which specific rules in your theme should apply to the component. Rule names can follow MUI conventions found on the API pages for components. For example, if creating a custom Button one could use [Button API](https://mui.com/material-ui/api/button/#css) rule names such as: *root*, *text*, and *textInherit*, *textPrimary*, *textSecondary*. etc.

The **slot** property appears to have one use case. As defined on the [styled MUI docs page](https://mui.com/system/styled/#api): *If Root, it automatically applies the theme's variants*.

As an aside: The **label** property is applied as a suffix to class names and can be used with css [attribute selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Building_blocks/Selectors#attribute_selectors) such as *contains* (*=) or *ends-with* ($=).